# using scalatest in a playframework project

Tags: playframework, sbt, scalatest

Im working on a playframework project in scala. Our team however wants to use scalatest instead of specs. I've added the following to the plugins.sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.7.1" "test"
```

But when I start play, no new jars are being downloaded, not even after running

```
update
```

and when i run

```
library-dependencies
```

it shows me this

```
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9.1, play:play:2.0, play:play-test:2.0:test)
```

Also when I try to test I get a compile error saying that org.scalatest is not in the buildpath. Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should modify project/Build.scala, and better to use like the following:-

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  // Add your project dependencies here,
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.7.2" % "test"
)
```

Please use the version 1.7.2, which contains a bug fix in SBT integration.

Also, you'll need to set the testOptions to Nil:-

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here    
      testOptions in Test := Nil
    )
```

This is because Play 2.0 by default will send the following Specs 2 test options in, which are:-

sequential true junitxml console

They are not recognized by ScalaTest, so setting testOptions to Nil should fix it.

Comment: Thank you, it has downloaded the jar, but when i try to run i get an error, test-listeners: java.net.UnbnownHostException: (none): (none).

Answer (score 1):

You should modify project/Build.scala, make the following change

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  // Add your project dependencies here,
    "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.9.1" % "1.7.1"
)
```