# Play! framework: customize which tests are run

Tags: scala, testing, playframework-2.0, sbt, specs2

I have a Play! 2 for Scala application, and I am using Specs2 for tests. I can run all tests with the `test` command, or a particular specification with `test-only MyParticularSpec`.

What I would like to do is mark some particular specifications, or even single methods inside a specification, in order to do things like:

- running all tests that are not integration (that is, that do not access external resources)
- running all tests that do not access external resources in write mode (but still running the reading tests)
- running all tests but a given one

and so on.

I guess something like that should be doable, perhaps by adding some annotations, but I am not sure how to go for it.

> Does there exist a mechanism to selectively run some tests and not other ones?

**EDIT** I have answered myself when using `test-only`. Still the command line option does not work for the `test` task. Following the [sbt guide](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html#additional-test-configurations) I have tried to create an additional sbt configuration, like

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
  // more settings
  lazy val UnitTest = config("unit") extend(Test)
  lazy val specs = "org.scala-tools.testing" %% "specs" % "1.6.9" % "unit"

  val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA)
    .configs(UnitTest)
    .settings(inConfig(UnitTest)(Defaults.testTasks) : _*)
    .settings(
      testOptions in UnitTest += Tests.Argument("exclude integration"),
      libraryDependencies += specs
    )
}
```

This works when I pass arguments without options, for instance when I put `Test.Argument("plan")`. But I was not able to find how to pass a more complex argument. I have tried

```
Tests.Argument("exclude integration")
Tests.Argument("exclude=integration")
Tests.Argument("-exclude integration")
Tests.Argument("-exclude=integration")
Tests.Argument("exclude", "integration")
Tests.Argument("exclude \"integration\"")
```

and probably more. Still not any clue what is the correct syntax.

> Does anyone know how to pass arguments with options to specs2 from sbt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass several arguments you can add several strings to one `Test.Argument`

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("include", "unit")
```

There are examples of this in the *specs2* User Guide [here](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html#with+sbt+%3E+0.9.x) and in the Play documentation [there](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/SBTSettings).

Comment: Thank you very much! What is not explained well in the documentation is that here we have a single argument (exclude) with some options (what to exclude) and it is not clear that one should pass it like separate arugments. Actually, I had tried this (`Tests.Argument("exclude", "integration")`) but id did not work. I have now found out that the problem was not this declaration, but rather the fact that I was declaring the tag at the beginning of the spec `( "something" should { tag("integration")...`) rather than on the single fragemnt. I will try to find out what is not working with this.

Comment: I have also fixed this issue using the `section` call, so now everything is working. Thank you again! :-)

Comment: Good. I've amended the documentation for the next version of specs2: http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide-SNAPSHOT/guide/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html#with+sbt+%3E+0.9.x

Comment: You are really responsive. It is wonderful to get an answer from the author of the library and have the documentation amended in just a few hours! Thank you very much!

Comment: How do you execute integration test from SBT once they are excluded?

Comment: I think that you can override the options on the command-line with `test-only`: `test-only -- include integration`.

Answer (score 7):

First, following [the specs2 guide](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Structure) one must add tags to the specifications, like this

```
class MySpec extends Specification with Tags {
  "My spec" should {
    "exclude this test" in {
      true
    } tag ("foo")

    "include this one" in {
      true
    }
  }
}
```

The command line arguments to include are documented [here](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html)

Then one can selectively include or exclude test with

```
test-only MySpec -- exclude foo
test-only MySpec -- include foo
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use without any change to your build

```
test-only * -- exclude integration
```

Tested in Play 2.1-RC3

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Play2.2, and there are 2 ways to do this depending on whether or not you are in the play console.

1. From the console type: `test-only full.namespace.to.TestSpec`
2. From the terminal type: `test-only "full.namespace.to.TestSpec"`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while trying to figure out how to do something similar for ScalaTest with Play. SBT has detailed documentation on how to configure [additional test configurations](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing) but these could use a bit of tweaking for Play.

Apart from the subtly different Project configuration I found that I wanted to crib a bunch of the test settings from [PlaySettings](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlaySettings.scala). The following is running and generating an Intellij project with integration test sources in the "**/it**" directory. I may still be missing reporting and lifecycle hooks,

```
object BuildSettings {
  def testSettings = {
    // required for ScalaTest. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362388/using-scalatest-in-a-playframework-project
    testOptions in Test := Nil
  }

  def itSettings = {
    // variously cribbed from https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlaySettings.scala
    sourceDirectory in IntegrationTest <<= baseDirectory / "it"
    scalaSource in Test <<= baseDirectory / "it"
    libraryDependencies += "play" %% "play-test" % play.core.PlayVersion.current % "it"
  }
}

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
  val main = play.Project(
    appName,
    appVersion,
    Dependencies.dependencies)
    .configs( IntegrationTest )
    .settings(Dependencies.resolutionRepos)
    .settings(BuildSettings.testSettings)
    .settings(Defaults.itSettings : _*)
    .settings(BuildSettings.itSettings)
}
```